# How to save log files from docker container?

Tags: docker

I have a weblogic container running on docker-machine( which is running on Windows 7 using docker toolbox) and want to save the logs from the container automatically to the windows machine.

I know that I can use the `docker cp` command but, instead of coping the logs every time to the windows machine, is there a better way to save the logs from the container to a folder on windows machine?

Comment: Look up docker volumes. You can expose a part of the host file system to the container

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that worked!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See "[Docker Logging Strategies](https://www.loggly.com/docs/strategies-for-docker-logging/)", which illustrates different methods.
The recommended one is logging via the [Docker Logging Driver](https://www.loggly.com/docs/docker-logging-driver/).
See more at "[Configure logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/)"

As shown in "[Better ways of handling logging in containers](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/10/playing-with-docker-logging/)", you can then link the log folder with an host folder through a [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container).

```
# docker run -ti -v /dev/log:/dev/log fedora sh
```