# saving docker log files with volumes produces permission denied

Tags: docker, permission-denied, docker-volume

I am trying to test saving log files of docker containers in playing in [this site](http://labs.play-with-docker.com/) which gives you a linux root shell with docker installed. I'v used solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772159/how-to-save-log-files-from-docker-container?answertab=active#tab-top):

```
docker run -ti -v /dev/log:/root/data --name zizimongodb mongo
```

This is what I got in the console:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/dev/log\\\" to rootfs \\\"/graph/overlay2/7f1eb83902e3688c0a1204c2fe8dfd8fbf43e1093bc578e4c41028e8b03e4b38/merged\\\" at \\\"/graph/overlay2/7f1eb83902e3688c0a1204c2fe8dfd8fbf43e1093bc578e4c41028e8b03e4b38/merged/root/data\\\" caused \\\"permission denied\\\"\"".
```

But the container has started:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
8adaa75ba6f7        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   2 minutes ago       Created                                 zizimongodb
```

`docker logs -f zizimongodb` returns nothing. When I stop the container, nothing is saved in the `/root/data`. Any idea how I can correctly save all logs?

Comment: Why are you using `/dev/log` ? Try using `/var/log/mongodb:/root/data`

Comment: @TarunLalwani, first of all I have a lot of components which I want to get their log from their containers; I want to save docker logs in order to access all of them. Secondly, I tried your suggestion, nothing has been saved after stopping and then removing container.

Comment: Well that is because `mongo` doesn't share logs on `/root/data`. If you check mongodb container the logs are sent to `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`. So why do you expect it to work?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, `/root/data` is my host directory and `/var/log/mongodb` is the container directory. I am trying to mount container directory into host directory in order to save contents of container directory into my host directory; so I can access it after stopping or removing my container. Am I doing wrong to achieve this?

Comment: The format is `hostpath:containerpath`. You need to use `/root/data/logs/:/var/log/mongodb/`. This will get every log from inside the container to `/root/data/logs` on your host

Comment: @TarunLalwani, you are right; but I tried and still not getting logs saved in the host directory.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using the official mongo image from DockerHub, it is worth pointing out that this official image (like many--or all?--of the official images) does not send log output to their **default log** locations that you might expect if you download a Linux distro version of the same software.

Instead, most software that is capable of being told where to log, are forced to log to stdout/stderr so that docker log plugins and the `docker log` command itself work properly.

For the mongodb case you can see this somewhat complicated code [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/a625cc00167b598f6902de0824519196410074f4/3.5/docker-entrypoint.sh#L184) that tells the mongodb process to use the `/proc` filesystem file descriptor that maps to "stdout", as long as it is writeable when the container is started. Because of some bugs this is more complicated that other `Dockerfile` customization of log output (you can read more if interested at the links in the comments).

I think a more reasonable way to try and do some form of log consolidation or collection is to read about [docker log drivers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/overview/#supported-logging-drivers) and see if any of those options works for you. For example, if you like `journald` there is a driver which will take all container logs and pass them to journald on the host.

Comment: Often it's more convenient to have logs in a proper file. Having them in `docker logs` may be an additional feature, but I believe you should still keep the log as files.