# Saving logs from docker container to windows file system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i just started learning docker and am interested in saving logs from container to local machine(for storage/review)
Is there a way to save /var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_ID-json.log to Windows filesystem?

i tried specifying volume in my docker-compose.yml file running image "dtf"

```
services:
  web:
    image: dtf
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1k"
        max-file: "3"
    volumes:
      - C:\logs:/var/lib/docker/containers/
```

from what i understood about docker volumes, i should be able to access the .log file at C:\logs, but i'm not sure how to correctly write path to the file itself (the /CONTAINER_ID/ part)

Comment: Are your logs being stored inside the docker container somewhere? Or is the application printing the logs to stdout?

Comment: command
`docker logs image_name`
prints previous logs, so i assume they have to be stored?

Comment: The logs from a container are stored in the host machine at a location in `json` format. (is you're us8ing the default log-driver). I'm assuming that's not the logs you want. You want the logs that the container spewed out. Hence my question, is your app writing it's log to a file or printing to stdout?

Comment: probably to stdout, if that's what gets printed after `docker logs image_name` command

Comment: Then you need to save the output `docker logs` to you local system. Check how you can do output redirection in Windows

Comment: Hey, i have the same problem and i'm new to docker. Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score -3):

For this you need to look up docker volumes. You can expose a part of the host file system to the docker container. 
Check out [Docker logging strategies](https://www.loggly.com/docs/strategies-for-docker-logging/) which illustrates different approaches to perform logging. The recommended method is [Docker logging driver](https://www.loggly.com/docs/docker-logging-driver/), please check out more at [Configuring logging drivers](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/).

As shown in [Better ways of handling logging in containers](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/10/playing-with-docker-logging/), you can link the log folder with a host folder via a [data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) using this command:

```
# docker run -ti -v /dev/log:/dev/log fedora sh
```

The above solution has been taken from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42772751/6138595), and just provided the answer in case the original solution link becomes obsolete due to deletion or something.

Comment: i tried creating volume as such `C:\logs:/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/` but it doesn't appear to contain any .log files, while `docker logs image_name` does print log entries

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22784614)

Comment: I have modified my answer to show the same original suggestion in the link previously provided in case that link becomes obsolete. Thanks for the suggestion @Andrey